# Doubt in a deduction from complex analysis to be uses in analytic number theory

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

While studying Analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory I have a doubt in proof of theorem 12.3 .

Proof is - [image]

> I have doubts in first paragraph of proof.
>
> 1. Why doesn't Apostol mentions that uniform convergence is to be proved  for a compact disk of |s|$\leq \epsilon $  where this compact disk lies in $C_2$  as it is proved for $C_1$ and $C_3$ . Then how can author be sure that I(s, a) would be analytic in $C_2$ .
> 2. Apostol then writes as integrand is entire function  of s this will prove that I(s, a) is entire.
>    If integrand is entire then how does it proves that I(s, a) is entire. Can someone please prove it.

Can someone please explain these 2 doubts.

Comment: The integral over finite length parts are trivially analytic.

Comment: @reuns 1. can you please tell why it is " trivially " analytic? 2.how to prove statement 2 ?

Comment: You have asked such a tremendous number of these questions, but I'm having trouble determining your background. Statement 2 comes from a foundational result in complex analysis: roughly, if a sequence of holomorphic functions $f_n$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on all compact sets, then $f$ is holomorphic. A flavor of this result will appear in any text on complex functions.

Comment: @daviddlowryduda you said I have asked tremendous amount of such question. How? Total questions asked by me are 12 only!! What do you want to know about my background?

Comment: @Dxdxdada david was presumably making a point about frequency, not necessarily just the number of questions you've asked.

Comment: @daviddlowryduda I know the fundamental result that you mentioned in your comment but I don't think your argument will prove the doubt 2 . Can you please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your confusion in 1 is you are switching variables in your head. We want to show for fixed $a$, $I(s,a)$ is entire in $s$. However, the curves $C_1,C_2$ and $C_3$ are defined in the $z$ variable. So you don't need to show uniform convergence for small disks as a separate case. There is no direct interplay between the disk in $s$ and the curves defined in $z$. So, if you show uniform convergence for arbitrarily large disks in the $s$ variable, you are finished.

Implicitly, the author thinks of $I(s,a)=I_1(s,a)+I_2(s,a)+I_3(s,a)$ where $I_j$ is integrating over $C_j$. To the author , it is clear $I_2$ is entire as the integrand is holomorphic in $z$ in some domain containing $C_2$.

Proving 2 for finite length curves is tantamount to proving you can differentiate under an integral in appropriate circumstances. For curves of infinite length, you need to do some work involving bounds and uniform convergence. (as the author does).

Suppose $f(s,z)$ is defined on $U\times V$ and is holomorphic in either variable while the other is fixed. Let $C$ be a finite length curve in $V$. Then $I(s)=\int_C f(s,z) dz$ is holomorphic and $I'(s)=\int_C f_s(s,z) dz$. Proof: differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: Ó Raghaillaigh. Bounty expires in 1 hour. Couldn't read your answer as I have important work to do but giving bounty to you as you have answered .

Comment: O Raghaillaigh Can you please tell which result can be exactly used in question 2 asked by me?

Comment: I edited above if you need more info just ask.