# Doubt in proof of valence formula of entire modular forms

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am self studying analytic number theory from lecture notes of Peter Bruin and Sanders Dahmen.

I have a doubt in proof when the authors writes the identities involving order of zeroes. I am posting the image highlighting the the part I have doubt.

Image - [image]

[image]

> My doubt is ->How the authors write the last 3 identities in the 2 nd image which are highlighted.

Can someone please help by explaining any 1 identity.

Comment: This already has an answer here so I would suggest you re-ask the question on MO if you would still like to ask it there. (Be sure to include what you're looking for in an answer explicitly.)

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{C'}^C$ is an integral over a simple closed-loop around the point $SL_2(Z)i$ of the modular curve, thus for $f$ meromorphic and $SL_2(Z)$ invariant,
$$\int_{C'}^C\frac{f'}f =2i\pi \ ord_{SL_2(Z)i}(f)$$ (where $ord_i(f) = 2ord_{SL_2(Z)i}(f)$)

$\int_{B'}^B+\int_{D'}^D$  is an integral over a simple closed-loop around $SL_2(Z)e^{2i\pi /3}$.

To extend those things to modular forms $f\in M_k(SL_2(Z))$, we need to let the radius of the piece of circles $\to 0$,

or arg that  $g=f/E_k$ is $SL_2(Z)$ invariant and $g'/g=  f'/f-E_k'/E_k$.

Comment: 1. which result are you using to write that 1st integral which is from C' to C = 2πi ord f (i) ? 2. How are you sure that f'/f has no poles only zeroes? 3 . I suspect if you are using argument principle the on RHS you would get 2πi × ( Number of zeroes) .  Then how no. Of zeroes = order of zero as order of zero is smallest c(r) such that c(r) $\neq$ 0 .

Comment: Again I'm taking a chart $\phi : 0\to SL_2(Z)i$ then $\int_{C'}^C\frac{f'}f=\int_{|s|=r} \frac{(f\phi(s))'}{f \phi(s)}ds=2i\pi \ ord_0(f\phi)$. If you let the radius $\to 0$ all you need is to know that $f'/f$ has a simple pole of residue $2 ord_{SL_2(Z)i}(f)$ at $i$

Comment: it s my humble request can you please answer this question. I would be really thankful to you. I don't have any other help except this app. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496833/doubt-in-a-deduction-from-complex-analysis-to-be-uses-in-analytic-number-theory

Comment: I will do a course on Riemannian geometry next semester. Can you please tell how to do it without using charts!!